# For $\langle f_v \rangle :=\{p \in \mathbb{F}[x] \mid p(A)v=0 \}$ when is $f_v = m_A$? ($m_A(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to solve the following problem, but cannot seem to complete it:

> Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}, n>0$ over a
> field $\mathbb{F}$, and let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$.
>
> Every $v \in V$ has a polynomial $f_v \in \mathbb{F}[x]$
> such that $\langle f_v \rangle = \{p \in \mathbb{F}[x] \mid p(A)v=0 \}$. When is it the case that $f_v=m_A(x)$? (where $m_A(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$).

**EDIT:** the approach I took below may be wrong. It is possible that it there is a way to go about this using the fact that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $(V,T)$ (where $T$ is the linear transformation corresponding to $A$) and $(V, \cdot)$ as an $F[x]$-module, and then viewing $f_v$ and $m_A(x)$ as part of the fundamental theorem for finitely generated $F[x]$-modules (e.g. $F[x]/\langle m_A(x) \rangle$).

My approach:

If $v=0$ then every polynomial $p$ satisfies the condition $p(A)v = 0$ so $f_v = 1$ and this cannot be a minimal polynomial. So a necessary condition must be that $v \neq 0$.

Assume $v \neq 0$.

In this case, I started by trying to assume that $f_v\neq m_A(x)$ to see if this bears any consequence on the rational canonical form of $A$ (i.e. looking for some condition such as 'the rational canonical form cannot have a block of the form X'). Under this assumption, there must be a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $m_A(x) \nmid p(x)$ and for which $p(A)v = 0$.

Since $p(A) \neq 0$ there must be at least one block, $C(a_i(x))$ in the rational canonical form of $A$ such that $P(C(a_i(x)))\neq 0$.

From this point, I wasn't sure what else I could do, so I tried plugging in options for simple forms of rational canonical forms and basis vectors $e_i = (0,1,0..)$ to see what might come of it, but this didn't lead to anything fruitful.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's a weird question and I'm not sure what answer it is looking for.  There are various necessary or sufficient conditions you could give but there is no obvious "canonical" necessary and sufficient condition that would be the expected answer.

Comment: A closely analogous question would be: given a finite abelian group $G$ and an element $v\in G$, when is the order of $v$ equal to the exponent of $G$?  That's not really a question that has a simpler answer than "when it is".

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks. My professor threw it out there as a question that is 'good practice for this topic', so I suppose he had something in mind. It was somehow brought up in the context of rational canonical form discussion, so I'm assuming that was the way he intended to go about it.

Comment: $f_v=m_A$ iff $\deg(f_v)=\deg(m_A)$ iff the $A^k v,k\in 0\ldots \deg(m_A)-1$ are linearly independent. What do you want more?

Comment: Also unclear if you understood that $f_v$ is the minimal polynomial of $A|_{W_v}$ where $W_v=\Bbb{F}[A]v$ is the subspace spanned by the $A^k v,k\ge 0$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks! I'm wondering if you can expand why $f_v$ is the minimal polynomial of $A|_{W_v}$?

Comment: $f_v(A|_{W_v})=0$ and every polynomial such that $p(A|_{W_v})=0$ is a multiple of it.